# Why won't textbox validation within a custom window work?

Tags: wpf, validation, custom-controls

I am building a WPF application (abiding to the MVVM design pattern) and the validation I have applied to the properties of my models works fine (the code part) regardless of what type of window the textbox is within. However, regarding the default Validation.ErrorTemplate for a textbox which gives it a red outline if there is an error... well this only shows when the textbox is used with a standard Window, and doesn't if it is within my CustomWindow or CustomDialog. Both of these custom controls inherit from the Window class and only override aesthetical features of the base Window.

To re-iterate the point that the problem definitely lies within my custom windows - I can literally swap the xaml tags from CustomWindow to Window and all is well.

So, what I am thinking is that I need to specifically define a Validation.ErrorTemplate within the theme for the custom windows, i.e. like when you override a button template - if you don't define an on hover style it won't have one! BUT I have no idea how to go about doing this and/or if it is even possible and I can't find anything to help me via Google.

Any advice/guidance/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you somehow replace the control templates of the custom windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found another question related to my problem and a solution that works!

I had left out the adorner layer in the control templates for my custom windows. I don't want to steal the solution so please see the original answer here - [Error template not working when a ControlTemplate is applied to the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688790/error-template-not-working-when-a-controltemplate-is-applied-to-the-window).

Answer (score 0):

It *is* indeed possible. Take the following example (from the linked page at MSDN):

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Now we define the template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can find out more from the [Validation.ErrorTemplate Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: I have tried this, for some reason it doesn't work within my custom windows though! Extremely puzzled as to why not :S Thanks for the reply though!